# How can I use conflicting libraries in latex?

Tags: math-mode, algorithms

I am trying to write a document that uses two other manuscripts which make use of different libraries that seem to overlap in functionality.
Specifically when I try to use

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e}
```

with these algorithm packages(`\usepackage{algpseudocode}`, `\usepackage{algorithm}`) I get a myriad of errors during the compilation of my document. All these errors seem to be related to the algorithm descriptions. When I remove that library I am getting a bunch of errors related to some of the algorithm code sections. E.g

> ```
> l.148 \SetAlgoLined
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g.,`\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, 
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

I was thinking of separating the documents but is there any other way to fix these problems?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: That's a tough one, because the problem seems to be specific to your document setup. You might consider locating the definition of the undefined macro(s) in the removed portion, and copying those definitions into the Preamble of your main document. Might need `\makeatletter` before them, `\makeatother` after.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't use `algorithm2e` along with other similar packages.

Comment: @egreg I already have in the tex code  the following: \usepackage{algpseudocode}, \usepackage{algorithm} but when I try to insert the \usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e} package I get a hundreds of compilation errors for some reason. How cna I resolve these problems?

Comment: Those packages are pretty much incompatible. You could try using `\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled, vlined,algo2e]{algorithm2e}`.

Comment: @JamesT I get some new errors:"\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ 
l.162 \State S
              Sort($L(k), L(k+1), S(k)$)
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.162 \State S
              Sort($L(k), L(k+1), S(k)$)
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed."

Comment: @JamesT note that the code where these errors appear actually works fine in the individual document containing it.

Comment: Then there is nothing more that can be done. If packages are incompatible then they cannot be used together, I am not sure anyone will be able to answer this other then to say they're incompatible

Comment: @JamesT maybe there is a way to insulate the parts that use that package from the rest

Comment: A "general" way is to modify the source code but this obviously requires TeX programming knowledge... another (easier) way is to just compile multiple PDF then `\includegraphics` appropriately

Comment: If the intent is just to have one document that contains to the two individual documents one after each other, then you might have a look at either https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/combine .  If your intention is to mix material from both documents in to a new main document, then you will have to settle on one package and adapt the code to that.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I will try them. Thank you for the comment.